# KV filter not including space values

Tags: logstash

The logstash `kv` filter is not including values with spaces. Please check below the input and output message generated by Logstash. The desired output should include spaces.

Input message:

```
key1=first value key2=second value key3=value3
```

Desired output:

```
{
    "key1" => "first value",
    "key2" => "second value",
    "key3" => "value3",
    "message" => "key1=first value key2=second value key3=value3"
}
```

Obtained output:

```
{
    "key1" => "first",
    "key2" => "second",
    "key3" => "value3",
    "message" => "key1=first value key2=second value key3=value3"
}
```

I need spaces in values to be included in fields. How to do this in Logstash?

Comment: The kv filter separates the key-value pairs (by default) with spaces. So when parsing `key1=first value key3=value3`, it will pick  `key1=first`, `value` and `key3=value3`. `value` is discarded since it does not have the key-value separator (`=`), then the two pairs are treated, giving `"key1" => "first"` & `"key3" => "value3"`.

Comment: You can't fix this with the kv filter, you'll have to modify the input before sending it to logstash, to something like this: `key1=first value, key2=second value, key3=value3`: with this you'll be able to use `,` as `field_split`

Comment: how to put , dynamically for those space? any approach in logtash?

Comment: I found something. I'll add as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `kv` filter separates the key-value pairs (by default) with spaces. So when parsing `key1=first value key3=value3`, it will pick `key1=first`, `value` and `key3=value3`. `value` is discarded since it does not have the key-value separator (`=`), then the two pairs are treated, giving `"key1" => "first"` & `"key3" => "value3"`.

This can't be fixed with the kv filter; you'll have to modify the input before sending it to `kv`, to something like this: `key1=first value, key2=second value, key3=value3` => with this you'll be able to use `,` as `field_split` in the `kv` configuration.

You can use `mutate` before the `kv` filter to add `,` between the key-value pairs like this:

```
mutate {
    gsub => ["message", "(\S+=)", ", \1"]
}
```

This will replace all non-whitespace characters before the `=` sign with itself preceded by `,` .

Then use:

```
kv {
    field_split => ","
}
```